# How to change past commit to include a missed file?

Tags: git, git-commit

I have committed a change and forgot to add a file to the change set. After other commits, I realized the file is now missing from a `HEAD^4` commit.

How do I rewrite a previous commit to include the missing file?

Comment: did you push these 4 commits?

Comment: @mvp nope, they are on my local git repository only.

Comment: Similar question, but having made a push: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74449281/how-to-change-past-commit-to-include-a-missed-file-having-made-a-push

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use [`git rebase --interactive HEAD~4`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#Changing-Multiple-Commit-Messages) and set `edit` option for the commit you'd like to amend.

Remember that you **should not** modify commits pushed to the remote repository this way. It's better to add a new commit with missing file in that case.

---

To make this more clear, first stash any current changes with `git stash`. Then, `git rebase --interactive HEAD~4`. You get the following in a text editor (note that you'll get 5 commits, in descending order):

```
pick 123e123 fifth last commit message
pick 321e122 fourth last commit message
pick 1d23e3f third last commit message
pick 987a987 second last commit message
pick 8a8a8a8 last commit message
```

Modify the change entry's prefix from `pick` to `edit`. That'd be `edit 321e122 ...` for the OP.

`git rebase` goes through the entries, in order. As there's only one we're changing, you'll only have one entry to change. Now, add your files with `git add`, and `git commit --amend` to amend the current commit with those added files.

Finally, `git rebase --continue` moves onto the next file. As there's only one, the rebase is complete

Comment: Thanks. Is that the case even if I am the only user of the remote repo? Wouldn't it allow me to do `git push -f` if I am sure the upstream didn't change?

Comment: If you are the only user of the remote repo it's ok to do the forced push.

Comment: I think these instructions are not detailed enough. On trying it the first time I got told "Cannot rebase: Your index contains uncommitted changes." I had already `add`-ed the missing files, so I did a commit with "xxx" as the message. Then I did the rebase command, and changed the "xxx" commit from "pick" to "edit". Then I did "git rebase --continue". Now when I look at the history I have "xxx" as the latest commit, and the earlier commit I wanted to add them to is unchanged! I wonder where my mistake was?

Comment: @DarrenCook You should use 'squash', not 'edit'. The instructions are detailed enough.

Comment: Squashing the last commit will not put the file in HEAD~4.

Comment: This is useful, although I needed some experimenting to get it done.

Comment: git add editedFiles;
git commit -m "Blah";
git rebase -i HEAD~5; // as now new commit added so we needed to rebase with 5 instead of 4.

now move the "Blah" commit to second line and change it from "Pick" to "s" (squash) which will squash the commit with HEAD~5 as commands are executed from top to bottom

Comment: Downvoted because not only do I agree with @DarrenCook, but for the dismissive attitude. Mvp's answer is better.

Comment: [Dominik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47662843/1295595) has the necessary detail to explain this answer. Without that detail, I wouldn't be confident enough to go messing around in my repository's history.

Answer (score 290):

I realize people can google and come here to find a simpler answer: **What if it was just the last commit?**
 (OP's question is for fixing the 4th commit back in history)

In the case you commit and realize you forgot to add some file **immediately**, just do:

```
# edited file-that-i-remember.txt
git add file-that-i-remember.txt
git commit

# realize you forgot a file
git add file-that-i-forgot.txt
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

Where `--no-edit` will keep the same commit message.

Easy peasy!

Comment: Worth mentioning, if the commits aren't pushed to the remote.

Comment: Yes, it is worth mentioning here in the comments: It is for using before **push**. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: One notice is that the commits before and after `--amend` have [different hashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926768/amend-a-commit-that-wasnt-the-previous-commit)

Comment: Great answer. This should actually be the accepted best answer

Comment: Thanks, but it can't be: OP asked for `HEAD^4`. Its ok the way it is, just as an addendum for reference. ;)

Comment: The number of times I've googled this just to find this answer... :)

Comment: I thought this was the answer to my problem, but it does not work if you already pushed.

Comment: What if the that last commit was already pushed? I can't find a question/answer for that...
So, created this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74449281/how-to-change-past-commit-to-include-a-missed-file-having-made-a-push

Answer (score 14):

If you have NOT pushed these 4 commits, you can do it as follows:

Create patch files for all these commits:

```
git format-patch -4
```

Rewind back by 4 commits:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~4
```

Add missing file:

```
git add missing-file
```

Commit it with `--amend`:

```
git commit --amend
```

Apply all saved patches back:

```
git am *.patch
```

---

If you have pushed, you should NOT use this method. Instead, just admit your blunder and create one more commit on top of HEAD which fixes this issue.

Comment: If you want to do this step-by-step it is easier to cherry-pick commits after the modified one, than to export them as a patch.

Comment: This is matter of taste. I like `git format-patch`/`git am` much better. Most importantly it gives you more confidence if you screw up something - commit saved as patch in physical file is your best safety net.

Comment: The real confidence lies in fact, that when operating on a git repository you never remove a thing. Old commits are available until you run `git gc` :)

Comment: This is trivial and obvious for you and me. But, for user who is just getting started and probably does not understand anything about git - this fact is not obvious at all.

Comment: These instructions seemed long-winded, but were quite simple and easy to follow. Thanks. (I'd just add a final step: `rm *.patch` )

Comment: Unnecessarily complicated. Why not just `git rebase -i HEAD~4` instead of all this?

Comment: @MichałMiszczyszyn: `git rebase -i` is not exactly safe, you can easily get to state as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800874. My method is much more safe

Comment: @mvp `git reset --hard HEAD~4` is not exactly safe if `format-patch` fails for some reason, smh. `rebase` is much safer.

Comment: @MichałMiszczyszyn: I've never seen `git format-patch` to fail. Even if it did, it does no harm. Failed `git rebase` is harmful.

Comment: I didn't say `git format-patch` is harmful, but certainly `git reset --hard HEAD~4` is. Failed `git rebase` isn't harmful at all.

Comment: @michal: to each their own. I respectfully disagree

Answer (score 9):

Although the accepted answer is correct, it lacks detailed instructions on how to perform editing a commit during a rebase process.

- First, start a rebase process:

  ```
  git rebase --interactive HEAD~4
  ```
- A list of commits will be presented, choose a commit you want to edit by changing the word `pick` to `edit` and save the file.
- Make necessary modifications in your code (remember to invoke `git add` for new files)
- After all modification are done, issue `git commit --amend` - this will amend a commit marked as `edit`
- Invoke `git rebase --continue` that will finish the process (if there are more commits marked as `edit`, the above steps need to be repeated)

**Important notes:**

- DO NOT remove lines marked as `pick` that you don't want to edit - leave them as is. Deleting these lines will result in deleting related commits
- GIT forces you to `stash` before rebasing if your working directory is not clean; you can however `git stash pop / git stash apply` during rebase, in order to amend these changes (i.e. changes stashed before starting the rebase process) to a commit marked as `edit`
- if something went wrong and you want to revert changes made during the rebase process before it finished (i.e. you want to revert to the point before starting the rebase), use `git rebase --abort` - also read: [How to abort an interactive rebase if --abort doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104649/how-to-abort-an-interactive-rebase-if-abort-doesnt-work)
- As said in the accepted answer:

  > Remember that you should not modify commits pushed to the remote repository this way. It's better to add a new commit with missing file in that case.

  The answer why, is in the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) (paragraph entitled "*The Perils of Rebasing*"):

  > Do not rebase commits that exist outside your repository.
  >
  > If you follow that guideline, you’ll be fine. If you don’t, people will hate you, and you’ll be scorned by friends and family.
  >
  > When you rebase stuff, you’re abandoning existing commits and creating new ones that are similar but different. If you push commits somewhere and others pull them down and base work on them, and then you rewrite those commits with git rebase and push them up again, your collaborators will have to re-merge their work and things will get messy when you try to pull their work back into yours.
  >
  > [...]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-interactive `rebase` approach.

This requires an extra commit (so does not "rewrite a previous commit" as asked by OP), but I find it easier to remember.

Initial state:

```
* e834111 (HEAD -> master) do something that depends on file x
* 6dde62a do stuff, forget to add file x
...
```

Step 1 - checkout a new temporary branch at the commit that should have included the file (`git checkout -b temp 6dde`):

```
* e834111 (master) do something that depends on file x
* 6dde62a (HEAD -> temp) do stuff, forget to add file x
...
```

Step 2 - `add` the missing file and `commit`:

```
* 50d1412 (HEAD -> temp) add file x
| * e834111 (master) do something that depends on file x
|/  
* 6dde62a do stuff, forget to add file x
...
```

Step 3 - checkout the original branch and `rebase` onto `temp`:

```
* dd6f2dd (HEAD -> master) do something that depends on file x
* 50d1412 (temp) add file x
* 6dde62a do stuff, forget to add file x
...
```

Step 4 - remove the temporary branch (`git branch -d temp`)

Note: This can also be done without creating a temporary branch, using e.g. `git checkout 6dde` followed by a `commit` and `rebase` onto the detached head.