# How do I add a file to the last local commit?

Tags: git

Sometimes I forget to add some files before commiting. With Mercurial I fix it this way:

1. `hg qinit`
2. Convert commit to patch
3. Update patch
4. Convert patch to commit

Can I do anything like this with Git?

Comment: In theory, you can override history locally:
- copy current content
- revert to previous version
- add all you need
- commit new commit as a new head

But... personally, I prefer to add another commit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37848143/828193

Comment: There is no difference between changing a commit message and changing a commit files. Both operations changes a commit. What's changed is just a detail.

Comment: Incidentally, there's a shorter way to do this in Mercurial. Just add and commit the file and then run `hg histedit`. You will be given the opportunity to `fold` (Git calls this `squash`) two commits into one new, different commit. See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HisteditExtension for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically trying to change your last commit in Git. This is possible and quite simple.

`git commit --amend` is used for this purpose.

The following page gives a detailed example.

https://github.com/abhikp/git-test/wiki/Changing-your-last-commit